# Solspace Calendar - Grid Field & Channel Images + Conditionals

Tags: solspace, grid, solspace-calendar, channel-images

I'm displaying a list of events and details on a page. Replacing the current channel:entries tag pair with the Solspace Calendar:Events tag.

I cannot work out how I am meant to display the current code (below) using the Calendar tags.

e_image is a channel_images field.
Adding {calendar:e_image} doesn't work.

```
    {if e_image}{e_image}
    <div class="ceimg2" style="background-image: url({image:url:esml})">
        <a href="{image:url:elrg}" title="{image:title}" class="large"><span>ENLARGE IMAGE</span></a>
    </div>{/e_image}
    {if:elseif e_map && ! e_image}
    <div class="ceimg1">
        <p>VIEW<br>MAP</p>
        <a href="{e_map}" target="_blank" title="VIEW MAP"><span></span></a>
    </div>{/if}
```

I have tried embedding it as a template using {exp:channel:entries channel="event" entry_id="?" dynamic="no"} but not sure if i am missing something or it's just not possible?

I also have the same issue with details in a Grid field - also tried embedding as a template (as noted in the docs) but cannot understand what I'm doing wrong.
Below is part of my original channel:entries code, with some added calendar:events tags.
How would I go about embedding this?

e_contact is the actual grid field, with ename, ephone, etc the individual grid columns.

```
        {e_contact}
        {if e_contact:count == "1"}<a href="tel:{e_contact:ephone}">{e_contact:ephone}</a> {e_contact:ename}{/if}
        {if e_contact:count == "2" AND "{e_contact:ephone}" != ""} &nbsp;<i>or</i> &nbsp; <a href="tel:{e_contact:ephone}">{e_contact:ephone}</a> {e_contact:ename}{/if}
        {if e_contact:count == "3" AND "{e_contact:ephone}" != ""} &nbsp;<i>or</i> &nbsp; <a href="tel:{e_contact:ephone}">{e_contact:ephone}</a> {e_contact:ename}{/if}
        {if e_contact:count == "4" AND "{e_contact:ephone}" != ""} &nbsp;<i>or</i> &nbsp; <a href="tel:{e_contact:ephone}">{e_contact:ephone}</a> {e_contact:ename}{/if}
        {/e_contact}
        {e_contact limit="1"}{if e_contact:ephone}{/if}{/e_contact}
        {e_contact}
        {if e_contact:count =="1" AND "{e_contact:eemail}" != ""}<a href="mailto:{e_contact:eemail}?subject={title} - {e_date format="%j%S %M %Y"}">{e_contact:eemail}</a>{/if}
        {if e_contact:count =="2" AND "{e_contact:eemail}" != ""} <i>or</i> &nbsp; <a href="mailto:{e_contact:eemail}?subject={title} - {e_date format="%j%S %M %Y"}">{e_contact:eemail}</a>{/if}
        {if e_contact:count =="3" AND "{e_contact:eemail}" != ""} <i>or</i> &nbsp; <a href="mailto:{e_contact:eemail}?subject={title} - {e_date format="%j%S %M %Y"}">{e_contact:eemail}</a>{/if}
        {if e_contact:count =="4" AND "{e_contact:eemail}" != ""} <i>or</i> &nbsp; <a href="mailto:{e_contact:eemail}?subject={title} - {e_date format="%j%S %M %Y"}">{e_contact:eemail}</a>{/if}
        {/e_contact}
        {e_contact limit="1"}{if e_contact:eemail}</span>{/if}{/e_contact}
```

ANY HELP is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use embeds, you need to make sure you're passing the entry ID from the `{exp:calendar:events}` tag over to the embedded `{exp:channel:entries}` tag inside the embed. That would look something like this:

Main template:

```
{exp:calendar:events
    channel="events"
    date_range_start="today"
    date_range_end="30 days"
    limit="20"
}
   {calendar:title} - {calendar:event_start_date format="%F %j, %Y"}
   {embed="path_to/template" entry_id="{calendar:entry_id}"}
{/exp:calendar:events}
```

Embedded Template:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="events"
    entry_id="{embed:entry_id}"
}
   STUFF
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Thankyou! Both {calendar:entry_id} and {embed:entry_id} was what I needed.